# Authorization dialog shows wrong API version

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, documentation

If you go on this [doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-notifications) and click on <kbd>Get Token</kbd>, you'll see this:

[image: Popup dialog highlighting the part with "V2.0 API"]

Minor bug, but still, I thought it would be nice to fix this inconsistency :)

Comment: Cross-site duplication in MSE [_Version label need to be update in Stack Exchange API Authorization page_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273807/312043)